# this way = in this way?

Tags: meaning

*In this way, plants store the sun’s energy.*

*This way, plants store the sun’s energy.*

Do they always mean exactly the same thing when used in the beginning of a sentence?

Also, is using one better than the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In explaining how something works in general, "In this way" is preferable.
 If you are comparing two or more different ways that something works, you might use "this way" and "that way" to describe a difference between two things.

For example,
"The sunlight causes photosynthesis within the plant's cells. **In this way**, plants store the sun's energy. Some plants should be kept in the most direct sunlight possible, since **this way**, the energy storage is maximized."

Comment: Thank you for your perfect answer, Jack!